# List order sensitivity

Tags: prolog

Given fact

```
likes([apples, oranges], john).
```

how could I query

```
 likes([apples, oranges], Who).
```

and

```
likes([oranges, apples], Who).
```

and get same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in `likes/2`, the first (list) argument is always manually sorted and contains no repetitions, query using

```
likes_list(Stuff,Person) :- sort(Stuff,Sorted), likes(Sorted,Person).
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to sort, I would do something like that:

File:

```
likes([apples, oranges], jo).

likes_find([],_).
likes_find([Head | Tail] , Who):-
    likes(List1 , Who),
    member(Head , List1),
    likes_find(Tail ,Who).
```

Test:

```
?- likes_find([oranges,apples],X).
X = jo .

?- likes_find([oranges,apples,fail_here_plz],X).
false.

?- likes_find([oranges],X).
X = jo .

?- likes_find([oranges,apples],jo).
true .

?- likes_find([apples,oranges],jo).
true .
```